# Firebase auth custom claims expire

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

I use custom claims in my app to permit access to some features of it. I set claims once user is logging in. After that I do not change custom claims.

Everything seems to work fine, but last time I get a lot of requests from users that they lost access to the features. From Cloud Functions I can see that their claims (one specific claim, I do not log all the claims) or all the token is "undefined". In Cloud Functions I do

```
console.log("claims: " + context.auth.token.claimid);
```

The result is "claims: undefined"

These users are not new to the app, they use it for some months. And I'm sure that they had the token and the claim before, otherwise the app would not work for them.

The question is: do custom claims expire? Or does token? I use anonymous auth, the app is for iOS (Android users seem to not have this issue).

**UPDATE**

Seems like the problem appered because we changed the app bundle id and imported new Google Services plist file. After that, old users got new anonymous auth profiles with no custom claims, instead of getting their old auth profiles.

Answer (score 2):

Custom claims do not expire. They remain in the user's token, until you set new custom claims.

So the most logical explanation is that somehow another call to set custom claims was made for the same user without any claims. We have no way of knowing where that call came from based on what you shared, but I recommend searching for other code/devs that uses the Admin SDK.

Comment: So you think that "undefined" applies to custom claims, not token? I should not worry about any expiration of anonymous token, right?

I ask you because custom claims are only set from Admin SDK (Cloud Functions). I checked that I do NOT set them in any other scenario, except for login and sign up. And users with problems did not use these scenarios after they did successfully signed up.

That is why I worry about the entire token.

Comment: The `undefined` in your question says that the ID token doesn't have a `claimid`. That's all we can know from the information in the question. It *is* definitely possible that the anonymous auth token got deleted/damaged, so I'd always recommend *also* allowing your users to upgrade to a non-anonymous account: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/anonymous-auth#convert-an-anonymous-account-to-a-permanent-account

Comment: Thanks. Could you just share some thoughts on about how the anonymous auth token can get damaged?

Comment: This'd be things like a damaged install of your app, or something similar. Honestly, this is impossible to troubleshoot remotely - so I'd recommend focussing your efforts on finding a common pattern between the users who have this problem.

Comment: Any more news here @Basylio?

Comment: Yes, I guess I figured it out. It results that I changed the bundle id of the iOS app and imported the new Google Services plist file. Because of that, when old users logged in, thinking they will have their old auth profiles with custom claims, we just gave them new profiles with no custom claims. So, I released a CloudFunctions function for these users to assign old custom claims to their new auth profiles. It may sound obvious, but I didn't think about it (problems after plist changes), because even with new plist there is the same old list of anonymous users in firebase.